# SceneImporter not loading MeshFaceMaterial textures in r68

Tags: three.js, blender, texture-mapping

I have a scene which I am exporting from Blender using the Three.js exporter. After a bit of trial and error I got it to export fine. When I tried to import it into Three, I got a few WebGL errors like `glDrawElements: range out of bounds for buffer`, which seemed to be related to the size or positioning of the imported object. I mucked around with some stuff related to size and eventually got it to load fine. However, none of my materials with textures are loading, EXCEPT one, which was an object with a single material applied to it.

Here's my pipeline

- Create base for the level in my three js editor tool
- Export this and import it into Blender for texturing/uv mapping (works fine)
- Objects can have a number of materials, one for each face really, each material can have a different texture mapped to it (all good, objects are uv unwrapped etc..,)
- Join all objects together (except one object which is a tree with a single material/texture applied to it)
- Export the Blender file as a JSON file via the Three.js exporter
- Load the file into Three using the SceneImporter

When it comes into Three, there are two objects, one is the tree which has a single texture mapped to its material. The other is a large geometry with 20 materials and textures mapped. This geometry does not have any textures displaying and just shows as a MeshLambertMaterial.

Has anyone else experienced any issues like this? Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the SceneImporter doesn't know what to do with these materials, but all the data is there, so you'll need to give it a little help.

Like so;

```
loader.load('sceneWithObjectOfManyFaceMaterials.json' , function(loaded)
{
    for(var key in loaded.objects) 
    { 
        var mesh = loaded.objects[key]; 

        if(mesh.material.materials)
        {
            mesh.material.materials.forEach(function(m , i)
            {
                m.map = loaded.materials[m.name].map;
            });
        }

        scene.add(mesh);
    }

    render();
});
```